# complex django filtering

Tags: python, sql, django, filter

So we have a really long custom query that we used custom SQL and a cursor to complete. But now something has changed such that we must use django filtering. I have been able to complete most of the change with basic filtering and [F Objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model), but the following SQL escapes me:

```
AND (current_date - field_name) <= 14
```

**Is there a way, in django filtering and not custom SQL, to filter on a specific field in a more complex way like this?**

note: I looked into [Q Objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q), but could not find a solution with those either.

Comment: `Q(field_name__gte= datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=14))` ?

Comment: That should work, don't know why I thought I couldn't move things around like that in the first place

Comment: Actually, you dont need the Q object, as filters are `AND` by default.